# Issue not yet resolve Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the error while running npm run android. please help

the error is

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
> Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
> Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 2 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 2 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (D:\myapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\myapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\myapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I'm running npm run android to run react native app on android emulator but getting above error